# JSON-file from POST method android

Tags: json

Our webclient has a post method. When I try to access this method using its link i get this json file:

```
{"user":   
{"userID":0,"username":null,"password":null,"email":null,"telephone":null,"firstName":null,
"lastName":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"street":null,"number":null,"zipcode":null,"city":null,                                            
"showPosition":false,"notificationEmail":false,"profielFoto":null,"deelnames":null,
"kosten":null,"trips":null,"enabled":true,"authorities":  
[{"authority":"ROLE_USER"}],"accountNonLocked":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true}}
```

However I need this JSON file converted to :

```
{"userID":0,"username":null,"password":null,"email":null,"telephone":null,"firstName":null,
"lastName":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"street":null,"number":null,"zipcode":null,"city":null,                                            
"showPosition":false,"notificationEmail":false,"profielFoto":null,"deelnames":null,
"kosten":null,"trips":null,"enabled":true,"authorities":  
[{"authority":"ROLE_USER"}],"accountNonLocked":true,"accountNonExpired":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true}
```

So without the first line.

How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: By extracting the JSON object named "user" within the JSON object you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONObject user = jo.get("user");
```

If you need that as a String,

```
user.toString();
```

Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to get a better understanding of your JSON objects.